# How to handle null arrays in JSONResponse

Tags: apex, json

Currently, I'm working on an HTTP class and trying to parse HTTPResponse to a custom class but I'm getting below exception.How to handle if a specific array in JSON response returns null

> Expected apolloBulkEnrichResponse.matches but found null

Expected JSON Response

```
{
"status":"success",
"error_code":null,
"error_message":null,
"total_requested_enrichments":2,
"unique_enriched_records":2,
"missing_records":0,
"credits_consumed":0.02,
"matches":[
  {
     "revealed_for_current_team":true,
     "email":"email_not_unlocked@domain.com",
     "email_status":"verified",
     "id":"61c2e2d4bbb92a0001509cce"
   ]}}
```

Sometime I'm getting below response:

```
{
"status": "success",
"error_code": null,
"error_message": null,
"total_requested_enrichments": 1,
"unique_enriched_records": 0,
"missing_records": 1,
"credits_consumed": 0,
"matches": [
    null
]
}
```

My code:

```
String jsonResponse = response.getBody();
jsonResponse = jsonResponse.replaceAll('\n','').replaceAll('\r','').replace('"number":','"phoneNumber":');
if (response.getStatusCode() == 200 ) 
    { 
        resp=BulkEnrichResponse.parse(jsonResponse);
    }
```

BulkEnrichResponse is a custom class:

```
  public static BulkEnrichResponse parse(String json) 
  {
    return (BulkEnrichResponse) System.JSON.deserialize(json,BulkEnrichResponse.class);
  }
```

Comment: How's your BulkEnrichResponse class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've reproduced your error with this simple class:

```
public class Sample {
    public List<SampleItem> items;
    
    public class SampleItem {
        public String name;
    }
}
```

And with this Anonymous Apex snippet:

```
String jsonString = '{"items": [ null ] }';
Sample s = (Sample) JSON.deserialize(jsonString, Sample.class);

System.debug(s);
```

Which gets me:

> Line: 15, Column: 1
> System.JSONException: Expected Sample.SampleItem but found null at [line:1, column:13]

---

## First of all

If you have access to the service/team that works with the external system, you could check with them to stop sending a null element within an array, which might not make much sense in your scenario (if there are no matches, wouldn't an empty list be more appropriate?).

## Secondly

If the above is not an option, you might want to approach this in two different ways:

### 1 - Parse the JSON string and remove the null element

Self-explanatory. Parse the String and remove the `null` part using the String methods available, such as `replace` and `replaceAll`. Doing so will have Apex interpret the list as what it actually is: an empty list.

> 11:31:44:008 USER_DEBUG [4]|DEBUG|Sample:[items=()]

### 2 - Deserialize the data into a Map<String, Object> instead

If you deserialize your object into a Map<String, Object> using `deserializeUntyped` instead, you'll have more work to instantiate your wrapper object, but you'll be able to catch these null items too:

```
String jsonString = '{"items": [ null ] }';
Map<String, Object> s = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonString);

System.debug(s);
System.debug(s.get('items'));
```

> 11:33:11:006 USER_DEBUG [4]|DEBUG|{items=(null)}

> 11:33:11:006 USER_DEBUG [5]|DEBUG|(null)

Comment: I've tried the first approach and it worked